# How to define a Map<String,CustomObject> in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a plugin as below

```
class AbstractConfigExtension {
    public static final String NAME = "abstract_extension"
    Project project

    // Configuration extension properties
    String service
    String substrate
    String region
    String group
    String pod
    Map<String,InstanceGridDetails> instanceGridDetails  = new HashMap<String,InstanceGridDetails>()
    // new HashMap<String,String>()
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>()
    List<String> instances = ["i01"]
    int numInstances = 1
    boolean generateServiceFiles = true
}
```

I have a different class called **InstanceGridDetails.groovy**

```
class InstanceGridDetails {
    // Grid Properties
    String grid
    String dsName
    String ddName

    public AcdsInstanceGridDetails () { 

    }

    String getGrid() {
        return this.grid
    }

    void grid(String grid) {
        this.grid = grid
    }

    String dsName() {
        return this.dsName
    }

    void dsName(String dsName) {
        this.dsName = dsName
    }

    String ddName() {
        return this.ddName
    }

    void ddName(String ddName) {
        this.ddName = ddName
    }
}
```

This is called as a plugin using the build.gradle as below

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: HoconConfigPlugin
apply plugin: GriddableCaacRpmPlugin

abstract_extension {
    service "relay"
    substrate "1p"
    region "xrd"
    instanceGridDetails = ["i01": InstanceGridDetails { gridName "grid1"
                                                            dsName "ds1"
                                                            ddName "dd1"} ]
    numInstances 1
    tags = ["medium_mem"]
}
```

when I am doing as above I am getting the issue as below

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'config-packages/service-cfg-1p-xrd/build.gradle'
>     line: 13
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':config-packages:service-cfg-1p-xrd'.
>
>   > Could not find method InstanceGridDetails() for arguments [build_b1plunv4uhm1dpn66jee47jiz$_run_closure1$_closure2@25cf3fbf] on
>   >     object of type AbstractConfigExtension.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is still called AcdsInstanceGridDetails while your class is called InstanceGridDetails. They should have the same name.

Try replacing all occurrences of AcdsInstanceGridDetails with InstanceGridDetails